# Crystal report export to editable MS Word

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, crystal-reports, export

I am using SAP Crystal Reports in VS 2010. I create a report like table structure (using lines). And export it to Word... I can even edit there. Everything works fine.

But what I want to:

1. I want to edit the generated reports in MS Word.
2. I can only add text but can't edit the report.
3. I want to use it like normal MS Word file.

Is there any alternate solutions for that?

I googled much, but can't find anything useful... so finally came here.

Thanks for reading.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve this thing you can't add constraint on crystal report to disable your report to edit.

But there can be a close solution that i will suggest that after exporting your report in MS word, apply the Restrict Editing on this document.

You have to write a chunk of code that might be your code or a service that do this task.

best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ExportOptions crExportOptions = report.ExportOptions;
{
   DiskFileDestinationOptions crDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
   PdfRtfWordFormatOptions crFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
   crDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = wordFilePath;
   crExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
   crExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.WordForWindows; //Or EditableRTF
   crExportOptions.DestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions;
   crExportOptions.FormatOptions = crFormatTypeOptions;
}
report.Export(crExportOptions);
report.Close();
```